# Flutter Pub: Expected a key while parsing a block mapping. path:

Tags: android, path, mapping, flutter, dart-pub

I'm using JSON file and register in `Pubspec.ymal` but showing error and also when I use an image and register it, the same error also occurs. Maybe there is a formatting mistake in it, but don't know what the problem is.this is the [doc](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec) I followed.

> **Error on line 29, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: Expected a key while parsing a block mapping**.
>   **assets:**
>       **^**

This is my `pubspec.yaml` file

```
name: jsondata description: A new Flutter application.

  dependencies:  

  flutter:

  sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.0

  dev_dependencies:   

 flutter_test:

      sdk: flutter

    flutter:

    uses-material-design: true

      assets:

       - loadjson/person.json
```

[image]

Comment: have  a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50171766/flutter-pub-expected-a-key-while-parsing-a-block-mapping-path)

Comment: Which line is line 29?

Comment: Try http://www.yamllint.com/

Comment: The `uses-material-design` should be on the same alignment vertically as the `assets`

Answer (score 299, accepted):

Spaces are significant in YAML

`assets` is indented too far

```
flutter_test:
  sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - loadjson/person.json
```

Comment: yamllint.com suggested below the question is probably a good advice to track down ll kinds of issues in yaml files.

Answer (score 27):

It is because of the indentation of your code.The `uses-material-design` should be on the same line vertically as the `assets:`.

```
 uses-material-design: true

 assets:
   - images/picture.png
```

Comment: Indentation is important, so make sure both are at same level. Left space should be same.

Comment: @Dan Thanks for your answer.The perfect one.

Answer (score 21):

> Error on line 29, column 4: Expected a key while parsing a block
>   mapping.    assets:
>
> flutter:   uses-material-design: true    assets: 
>       - assets/images/image.jpg

In my case i just added `#` in front of `uses-material-design: true`

Try below code

```
flutter:   

  # uses-material-design: true 

   assets: 
    - assets/images/image.jpg
```

its working fine.

Comment: That's probably because the indentation of `uses-material-design: true` was wrong. Commenting it out is not really an option if you want to use material.

Comment: I commented the `uses-material-design` and then did `Packages get` and then uncommented the same to re run on the simulator. Worked fine

Answer (score 11):

In my case, `uses-material-design` indentation was broken. I put 1 (one) more space before it, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 7):

With removed comments, original, generated by default pubspec.yaml looks like this

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
   assets:
    - images/abc.jpg
```

But it isn't vaild. It doesn't works. It should be:

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/abc.jpg
```

Important: Spaces are significant in YAML

Answer (score 4):

Spaces are very important in .yaml file.

Just make sure your code is on the same line (vertically) according to key and value.

**Or**

If you are still confused please watch this simple video. It'll help you to solve the issue easily.

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsFfV.jpg

Answer (score 4):

Assets should be on the same line as uses-material-design:

```
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/myimage.jpg
```

**Indentation Rules for pubspec.yaml**

- uses-material-design =  2 spaces
- assets = 2 spaces
- -images/  = 4 spaces
- fonts: = 2 spaces

  - -family: = 4 spaces
  - fonts:  = 6 spaces
  - -asset: = 8 spaces

Answer (score 3):

It is because Spaces are significant in YAML .The uses-material-design should be on the same line vertically as the assets:
It should be:

```
flutter:
 uses-material-design: true
 assets:
    - images/abc.jpg
```

If still you are getting error for line number same as assets. try **flutter clean** and **flutter pub get**.

Answer (score 2):

If `images` folder is next to `lib` folder, you need a `./`, because it is not on the same level as the `pubspec.yaml`, then, in `pubspec.yaml` uncomment:

```
assets:
- ./images/   //Watch for spaces and indentation!!
```

Now you can use them:

```
Image.asset(
          '../images/nature.png',
          width: 600,
          height: 240,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

**Error on line 46, column 4: Expected a key while parsing a block mapping. assets:

flutter: uses-material-design: true assets: - assets/dhaka.jpg**

Make sure when you uncomment the line please check indentation.
if indentation is wrong it's going error.
flowing this image.
Happy coding !!!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful with space in yml file

Answer (score 1):

Get same problem after uncommenting `assets` and `image link sample` in *pubspec.yaml*.

If you faced problem with `assets`, like I was. Make sure that it starts with same column(starts with same indent as pre-defined property like  `uses-material-design`). After uncommenting in my case, their location was different.

After that, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

In My Case, the image was too large to load, decreasing dimension of image worked.

Comment: You might want to add more details to be helpful for future people reading the your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that we don't have **unwanted whitespace** since **yaml structure is sensitively considering the white spaces**. Please refer the documentation for more info as below link,
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html

Answer (score 0):

As `@Baftek` mentioned , just indent before **uses-material-design:true** and press `Ctrl+Alt+l` (Intellij or Android Studio) to reformat file.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is related with indent spacing, check your spacing, it should work fine
fonts:
    - family: CM Sans Serif
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/cm_sans_serif_2012.ttf